# android studio. Nothing happens when i use intent.putextra

Tags: android, android-intent

I am new in this world. And im followering online guides to learn the language.

I am trying to get a notepad to work but i cant reopen the notes already created. 
I use the debugger but it seems to call the activity but it never opens.

The call.

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

            if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
                int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child);
                Note selectedNote = mNotes.get(position);
                Intent editorIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
                editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId());
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I can see editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId()); is calling the action with a id but when i look at the part who recieves the intent nothing happens.

```
public class NoteEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);


    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //remove this line in the MainActivity.java

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (args != null && args.containsKey("id")){
            long id = args.getLong("id", 0);
            if (id > 0){
                openFragment(NotePlainEditorFragment.newInstance(id), "Editor");
            }
        }
        openFragment(NotePlainEditorFragment.newInstance(0), "Editor");
    }
}
```

But in this code nothing react.

Can someone give me a hint??

Regards Danni.

Comment: You need to call `startActivity(intent)` to start the activity from intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

        if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child);
            Note selectedNote = mNotes.get(position);
            Intent editorIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
            editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

To

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

        if (child != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {
            int position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(child);
            Note selectedNote = mNotes.get(position);
            Intent editorIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
            editorIntent.putExtra("id", selectedNote.getId());
            startActivity(editorIntent);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

You need to call `startActivity` to begin the transaction from current activity to desired activity

And try to get id like this in next activity, use this code inside `onCreate()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
```

Comment: You need to call `startActivity` to begin the transaction from current activity to desired activity

Comment: I tried that several times. Then it calls the activity but without any content. So i am not sure that it gets the id right. Debugger says: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  Savedinstancestate: Null

Comment: Oh when i add the startActivity(editorIntent); i can see in the debugger it actually got the id with it. So there must be a other problem where it gets the content from the database. Thanks a lot. I worked on this for 6 days...